# How can I skip a job based on the changes made in .gitlab-ci.yml?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have two jobs in GitLab CI/CD: `build-job` (which takes ~10 minutes) and `deploy-job` (which takes ~2 minutes). In a pipeline, `build-job` succeeded while `deploy-job` failed because of a typo in the script. How can I fix this typo and run only `deploy-job`, instead of rerunning `build-job`?

My current *.gitlab-ci.yml* is as follows:

```yaml
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build-job:
  image: ...
  stage: build
  only:
    refs:
      - main
    changes:
      - .gitlab-ci.yml
      - pubspec.yaml
      - test/**/*
      - lib/**/*
  script:
      - ...
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ...
    expire_in: 1 hour

deploy-job:
  image: ...
  stage: deploy
  dependencies:
    - build-job
  only:
    refs:
      - main
    changes:
      - .gitlab-ci.yml
      - pubspec.yaml
      - test/**/*
      - lib/**/*

  script:
    - ...
```

I imagine something like:

1. the triggerer (me) fixes the typo in `deploy-job`'s script and pushes the changes
2. the pipeline is triggered
3. the runner looks at the files described by `build-job`/`only`/`changes` and detects a single change in the *.gitlab-ci.yml* file
4. the runner looks at the *.gitlab-ci.yml* file and detects there IS a change, but since this change does not belong to the `build-job` section AND the job previously succeeded, this job is skipped
5. the runner looks at the files described by `deploy-job`/`only`/`changes` and detects a single change in the *.gitlab-ci.yml* file
6. the runner looks at the *.gitlab-ci.yml* file and detects there is a change, and since this change belongs to the `deploy-job` section, this job is executed

This way, only `deploy-job` is executed. Can this be done, either using `rules` or `only`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a straight foward way, you just have to have access to gitlab CI interface.

1. Push and let the pipeline start normally.
2. Cancel the fist job.
3. Run the desired one (deploy).

Another way is to create a new job, intended to be runned only when needed, in which you can set a non-dependency deploy. Just copy the current deploy code without the dependencies. Also add the **manual** mode with

```
job:
script: echo "Hello, Rules!"
rules:
  - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
    when: manual
    allow_failure: true
```

As [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html).