# How to exclude gitlab-ci.yml changes from triggering a pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm looking for a way to avoid the triggering of gitlab pipeline when specific files have changed e.g. README.md. I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73523008/how-can-i-skip-a-job-based-on-the-changes-made-in-gitlab-ci-yml?rq=1) which touches upon the same thing, but there the accepted answer is how to simply avoid running a specific job. That can easily be achieved with `except` or `only` keyword for a specific stage.

There is one answer that seem to do what I want:

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if:
      changes: 
        - README.md
      when: never
```

But this does not work for me.

In short, how do I setup a workflow rule to except certain files to triggering a new pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing you pipline the following workflow rule should prevent your pipeline from running when `.gitlab-ci.yml` is changes:

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - changes: 
        - .gitlab-ci.yml
      when: never
```

But please be aware that `rules:changes` always evaluates to `true` when there is no git push event (from the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschanges)).